# Incompatible java version

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

when i check my java version with java-version i cmd i get this version:

```
openjdk version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-
21.0.1+12 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.1+12 (build 21.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

but when i type it in eclipse terminal i get different version:

```
openjdk version "17.0.4" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.4+8 (build 17.0.4+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.4+8 (build 17.0.4+8, mixed mode)
```

**I can't run jar files, and I think this is the issue
if anyone know how to fix it I'd be grateful.**

i've just downloaded the latest openJDK version, but i don't know how to update

Answer (score 2):

i think there is a mismatch between the Java version configured in your Eclipse IDE and the Java version you have installed on your system.

To resolve this:

1. open eclipse. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. Here, you can see the all the java versions, if the java version you want is not there, you need to add or update the Java version.
2. if you want to add, first you have to download the java version in your system and then add.
3. If you are working on a specific Java project, you may need to update the project configuration to use the correct Java version.

   Right-click on your project in the Project Explorer.

   Select Properties.

   Go to Java Build Path.

   In the Libraries tab, select the JRE System Library and click Edit.... Choose the appropriate Execution Environment or Alternate JRE.

My personal recommendation would be to restart the system after following the steps and after that try to check the java version on your eclipse.